# What is the difference between “I worry about you” and “I am worried about you”?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between “I worry about you” and “I am worried about you”? Could native speakers please explain it for me? Thank you.

Comment: Do you already understand the difference between "be worried" and "worry"?

Comment: I worry - habitual or frequent. I am worried - right now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm not native speaker but I can tell you about this.

> We use **`ed`** with adjectives to ***describe our feeling.***

1. I was worri`ed`.
2. She is shock`ed`.
3. You were annoy`ed`.

> We use **`ing`** with adjectives to ***describe the reason of my feeling.***(What/Who makes me to feel.)

1. It was embarrass`ing`.
2. This class is bor`ing`.
3. She was frighten`ing`. (means she was that reason, she scared me.)

The differences between ***I'm worried abou you & I worry about you***:

I'm worried: **`Subject`**+**`to be verb`**+**`adjective`**.

I worry: **`subject`**+**`verb`**.

When you say: I'm worried about you means you're telling them about your feeling.

When you say: I worry about you means you're doing an action (here this action is worrying about someone.)

Comment: "borned" is not a good example to use.  Also I think you mean "subject, not "sobject"